# Google sheets and automatic emails

Tags: email, google-sheets

I am wondering if anybody can help with this problem.

I am a teacher in a school and I am tracking if students are off track in subjects. The google sheet is shared with the whole school and then members of staff add if the students are off track or one track. If a student is off track in 2 or more subjects I would like an email to be sent to me so I can pick these students up. I would also like the email to be sent every week.

The logic seems simple enough, If the count of a certain amount of cells that equal "off track" then send email with value of first column which would be the name.

However I at banging my head on a wall as I don't really know how to add this to a google sheet.

I will give extra credit to any one that can help!!

Thank you every one

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this myself, but you will need to dig into code scripting on the sheet.  Also setup a trigger to run the script at a certain time.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

If you are not comfortable with coding, you can probably find someone on Odesk, Guru or Elance.  Someone from India could probably do it fast and cheap.